# How to create a scheduled file structure in OneDrive, SharePoint or another suitable platform

Tags: file, sharepoint, microsoft-teams, onedrive

I'm wanting to create a file structure for a university module such that I can place all my files in a folder at the start of the year, then each week's files automatically show to students at a scheduled time. For example, I would have a file structure similar to the below.

```
Module Folder Name
    -Week 1
      - Week 1's Documents
    -Week 2
      - Week 2's Documents
```

wherein week 1 students are not able to see week 2 until the week 2 lecture.

I could of course just add the files each week, but I wanted to see whether one drive, SharePoint or some other platform is capable of such a task, so that the uploading of files is automated.

The file structure would ultimately be embedded into teams.

Any insight into this would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you use SharePoint Server or SharePoint Online?

You could move files to corresponding folders in the SharePoint through [PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/08/sharepoint-online-move-all-files-from-one-folder-to-another-using-powershell.html).

Then you could run SharePoint Online PowerShell by using Power Automate.

References:

[Execute SharePoint Online PowerShell scripts using Power Automate](https://ashiqf.com/2020/05/26/execute-sharepoint-online-powershell-scripts-using-power-automate/)

[Run PowerShell on SharePoint from Azure Automation](http://www.msclouddeveloper.com/run-powershell-on-sharepoint-from-azure-automation/)

Comment: @trieasyboid- Is your issue resolved or still looking for any other solution?